# onclick event for span tag inside div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button that opens a image on my webpage and then when you press the x in the corner it closes. I got the image to open, but the close button isn't working and I don't know why.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = "image link";
}

function close(i) {
  document.getElementById(i).style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="schedule">
    <button id="myImg">
                  <h4><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Schedule</h4>
                  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <span class="close" style="z-index: 999;" onclick="close('myModal')">&times;</span>
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01" />
                  </div>
                </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: the span is a child of the button, so the click triggers a click on the parent button too (look up [event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture ). As a result the `close` function runs and sets the display to "none", but almost immediately after it's set back to "block" when the `img.onclick` executes.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan nope

Comment: @RobinZigmond ooohhh i see. is there a way i can fix this?

Comment: @memes - yes, of course. My favourite way here would be to see if you can restructure your HTML - it seems odd to me to have a click to close something INSIDE the thing you have to click to open it! If not possible, then use the `stopPropagation` method on the event object as that MDN article I linked to suggests. For that I think you'll have to add the click handler using `addEventListener` (the function you give that takes the event object as its only argument), rather than have `onclick="somefunction()"` - but you should be doing that anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a button inside a modal which is inside a button. That is a problem since the outer button prevents the inner button from working. Lets break those out a bit, and use a relative reference to close the modal.

First separate the modal from the button.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
}

function closeModal(el) {
  el.closest('.modal').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myModal {
  display: none;
}

.close {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close" style="z-index: 999;" onclick="closeModal(this)">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01" />
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="schedule">
    <button id="myImg">
             <h4><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Schedule</h4></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using relative references like that are handy when you have more than one element that can call them. Additionally it frees you from having to call an ID.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo on this line: `el.closest('.modal').style.display = "none";` - updated in answer

Comment: I updated my answer and made a snippet. There is an issue with the `close()` function name. Maybe it conflicts with the snippet or ? I changed the name and it works